# read spreadsheet online and dump data in folders using python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, file-handling

**this code which read spreadsheet online**

```
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = "example6565465dchdckjdISHEETID"
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv")

print(df)
```

**my folder structure to read csv file code is that**

```
import csv
import os


root = r'path'

with open(r"csv_path", 'r') as csv_file:
    df = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in df:
        set_name = row['Set_Name']
        asset_name = row['Asset_Name']
        asset_root = f"{root}/{set_name}/assets/{asset_name}"
        fixed_internal_folder = ['wip', 'exports']

        for folder in fixed_internal_folder:
            path = f"{root}/{set_name}/assets/{asset_name}/{folder}"
        os.makedirs(asset_root)
```

`

I want that if do any update in code then read spreadsheet and dump data in my folders if can then let me know
or any other way to do that then I want to know.
my expectation is that read spreadsheet online and update in folders at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this code Help you and try:

```
  import pandas as pd
    import os

root = f'F:/NEW_PROJECT/3D'
sheet_id = '1NUkyriW0pNLzHz28oVIL8Hi-kKnW9FZtnf7WccuS1jGa9ONI'
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv")

my_dict = df.to_dict()
dict_reader = my_dict.values()
# print(dict_reader)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    set_name = row['Set_Name']
    asset_name = row['Asset_Name']
    fixed_internal_folder = ['wip', 'export']

    for folder in fixed_internal_folder:
        asset_root = f"{root}/{set_name}/asset/{asset_name}/{folder}"
        os.makedirs(asset_root, exist_ok=True)
        print(asset_root)
```

In your code you can't iterate the rows and Index.